# Split a special windows in horizontal

Tags: window-splitting

I have known using `(setq split-width-threshold 1)` splitting windows in horizontal by default.

But I want to only split a window such as `slime` in horizontal and other window is vertical by default.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: check out [shackle.el](https://github.com/wasamasa/shackle)

Comment: With respect to setting a low value for either `split-width-threshold` and `split-height-threshold`, please read the doc-strings for the variables -- e.g., perhaps the value of `nil` is appropriate or a higher value.  `M-x describe-variable`.

Comment: See also -- "**How to force the window splitting direction when starting slime?**":  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/29123/how-to-force-the-window-splitting-direction-when-starting-slime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for @lawlist .

I have find the solution and known more about `split-width-threshold` and `split-height-thershold`.

By default, emacs will split window in horizontal when the window's columns greater then 160 columns.

Setting a integer number to split window sensibly or set `split-window-preferred-function` for a custom function for splitting.